# Laravel Eloquent to join table and count related

Tags: sql, join, laravel-4, eloquent

How do I use join with Eloquent taking in consideration the following table structure:

I have a properies table

```
---------------------
ID    | Name 
---------------------
1     | Property Name
```

than I have rooms

```
----------------------
RoomID | Property
----------------------
A-212  | 1
---------------------- 
F-1231 | 1
```

here Property is the foreign key
than I want to get all Properties and count how many rooms do they have each

The query which retrives all looks like

```
   class PropertiesRepository extends EloquentBaseRepository implements PropertiesInterface
{

    use TaggableRepository;

    /**
     * Construct 
     * @param Properties $properties 
     */
    public function __construct( Properties $properties )
    {
        $this->model = $properties;
    }
     /**
     * Get all properties joining rooms
     * @return Properties
     */
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->model->get();
    }
}
```

How do I extend this query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is more of a MySQL join+group+select trick which includes following steps.

1. Join your relation table(use `join` if you want to exclude rows with `RoomsCount=0`, else use `leftJoin`)
2. Use `groupBy` by primaryKey to avoid duplicates of the join.
3. Select `count` of joined table

```
    $this->model->leftJoin('Rooms', 'Properties.ID', '=', 'Rooms.Property')
      ->selectRaw('Properties.*, count(Rooms.RoomID) as RoomsCount')
      ->groupBy('Properties.ID')
      ->get();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and future researchers.  Stack Overflow wants to be more than just a snippet dumping ground.  Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 14):

Define the relationship on your Property model class:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;

class Property extends Model {
  public function rooms() {
    return $this->hasMany(Room::class);
  }
}
```

```
$properties = Property::withCount(['rooms'])->get();
```

This will add a rooms_count to the result.

Comment: It is okay to use this but please be aware this will run two queries internally.

Comment: You would have to define a belongsToMany relationship instead of hasMany. Everything else remains the same. 

See here on how to define a many-to-many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many