# Count number of rows from a different table using join on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I use eloquent to count rows of another table joined with the main table?

I have three tables:

- clients
- sms notification
- email notification

I want to join them by pulling the client list first, then count how many times they had notification from both SMS and email. Finally returning the count or 0 if no notification has been sent.

[image]

I found a sample: 
[Laravel Eloquent to join table and count related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648554/laravel-eloquent-to-join-table-and-count-related)

I used this for emails:

```php
<?php

$clients = Client::where('cl_delete_status', false)
    ->leftJoin('insura_communication_emails', 'insura_clients.cl_id', 'insura_communication_emails.cl_id')
    ->leftJoin('insura_communication_sms', 'insura_clients.cl_id', 'insura_communication_sms.cl_id')
    ->select('*', DB::raw('count(ice_id) as total'))
    ->groupBy('insura_clients.cl_client_id')
    ->orderBy('insura_clients.cl_id', 'desc')->get();
```

How can I put both tables that are email and SMS `insura_communication_sms` and in the code above? It skips those with 0 counts in the email notification.

Comment: Add another left join same way you have your first leftJoin, rather than count you might want to use `SUM`.

Comment: i can, but the count, how will i do that?

Comment: Prix can you show me how? i have added another left join to the code

Comment: if you can post some sample data https://www.db-fiddle.com/ sure.